# Repetition of results [CLIPS]

Tags: clips

```
(deftemplate path
(slot start) 
(slot end)
(multislot path) 
(slot cost(type NUMBER)))

(deftemplate info
(slot start) 
(slot end)
(multislot path) 
(slot cost))


(deftemplate startend
   (slot start)
   (slot end))



(deffacts variable_table

(path (start A)(end B)(path A,a,b,B)         (cost  7))
(path (start A)(end C)(path A,a,b,c,C)       (cost   10))
(path (start A)(end D)(path A,a,m,n,d,D)     (cost 8.5))
(path (start A)(end E)(path A,a,m,n,E)       (cost 5.5))
(path (start A)(end F)(path A,a,m,n,k,g,f,F) (cost  9.4))
(path (start A)(end CS) (path A,a,m,n,k,CS)  (cost  6.7))
(path (start A)(end G)(path A,a,m,n,k,g,G)   (cost 8))
(path (start A)(end H)(path A,a,m,n,d,e,H)   (cost 10.3))
(path (start A)(end I)(path A,a,m,I)         (cost 3.5))

(path (start B)(end A) (path B,b,a,A)        (cost   7  ))
(path (start B)(end C) (path B,b,c,C)        (cost  4))
(path (start B)(end D) (path B,b,c,d,D)      (cost 7 ))
(path (start B)(end E) (path B,b,g,k,n,E)    (cost 5.8  ))
(path (start B)(end F) (path B,b,g,f,F)      (cost  4.7))
(path (start B)(end CS)(path B,b,g,k,CS)     (cost  4.6))
(path (start B)(end G) (path NG2,b,g,G)      (cost  3.3))
(path (start B)(end H) (path NG2,b,g,f,e,H)  (cost 6.5 ))
(path (start B)(end I) (path NG2,b,g,k,n,m,I)(cost 7.8 ))

(path (start C)(end A) (path C,c,b,a,A)      (cost   10))
(path (start C)(end B) (path C,c,b,B)        (cost   5))
(path (start C)(end D) (path C,c,d,D)        (cost   4))
(path (start C)(end E) (path C,c,d,n,E)      (cost   5.3))
(path (start C)(end F) (path C,c,d,e,f,F)    (cost   7.6))
(path (start C)(end CS)(path C,c,b,g,k,CS)   (cost   7.6))
(path (start C)(end G) (path C,c,b,g,G)      (cost  6.3))
(path (start C)(end H) (path C,c,d,e,H)      (cost   5.8))
(path (start C)(end I) (path C,c,d,n,m,I)    (cost  9))

(path (start D)(end A) (path D,d,n,m,a,A)    (cost  8.5))
(path (start D)(end B) (path D,d,c,b,B)      (cost  7))
(path (start D)(end C) (path D,d,c,C)        (cost  4))
(path (start D)(end E) (path D,d,n,E)        (cost  5))
(path (start D)(end F) (path D,d,e,f,F)      (cost  5.6))
(path (start D)(end CS)(path D,d,n,k,CS)     (cost  6.2))
(path (start D)(end G) (path D,d,e,f,g,G)    (cost  6))
(path (start D)(end H) (path D,d,e,H)        (cost  3.8))
(path (start D)(end I) (path D,d,n,m,I)      (cost  7))

(path (start E)(end A) (path E,n,m,a,A)      (cost  5.5))
(path (start E)(end B) (path E,n,k,g,b,B)    (cost  5.8))
(path (start E)(end C) (path E,n,d,c,C)      (cost  7))
(path (start E)(end D) (path E,n,d,D)        (cost  5))
(path (start E)(end F) (path E,n,k,g,f,F)    (cost  5.9))
(path (start E)(end CS)(path E,n,k,CS)       (cost  3.2))
(path (start E)(end G) (path E,n,k,g,G)      (cost  4.5))
(path (start E)(end H) (path E,n,d,e,H)      (cost  6.8))
(path (start E)(end I) (path E,n,m,I)        (cost  4))

(path (start F)(end A) (path F,f,g,k,n,m,a,A)(cost   9.4))
(path (start F)(end B) (path F,f,g,b,B)      (cost   4.7))
(path (start F)(end C) (path F,f,e,d,c,C)    (cost  7.6))
(path (start F)(end D) (path F,f,e,d,D)      (cost  5.6))
(path (start F)(end E) (path F,f,g,k,n,E)    (cost  5.9))
(path (start F)(end CS)(path F,f,g,k,CS)     (cost   4.7))
(path (start F)(end G) (path F,f,g,G)        (cost   3.4))
(path (start F)(end H) (path F,f,e,H)        (cost   3.8))
(path (start F)(end I) (path F,f,g,k,n,m,I)  (cost  7.9))


(path (start CS)(end A) (path CS,k,n,m,a,A)  (cost  6.7))
(path (start CS)(end B) (path CS,k,g,b,B)    (cost  4.6))
(path (start CS)(end C) (path CS,K,g,b,c,C)  (cost  7.6))
(path (start CS)(end D) (path CS,k,n,d,D)    (cost  6.2))
(path (start CS)(end E) (path CS,K,N,E)      (cost  3.2))
(path (start CS)(end F) (path CS,k,g,f,F)    (cost  4.7))
(path (start CS)(end G) (path CS,k,g,G)      (cost  3.3))
(path (start CS)(end H) (path CS,k,g,f,e,H)  (cost  6.5))
(path (start CS)(end I)(path CS,k,n,m,I)     (cost  5.2))

(path (start G)(end A) (path G,g,k,n,m,a,A)  (cost       8))
(path (start G)(end B) (path G,g,b,B)        (cost  3.3))
(path (start G)(end C) (path G,g,b,c,C)      (cost  6.3))
(path (start G)(end D) (path G,g,f,e,d,D)    (cost  6))
(path (start G)(end E) (path G,g,k,n,E)      (cost  4.5))
(path (start G)(end F) (path G,g,f,F)        (cost  3.4))
(path (start G)(end CS)(path G,g,k,CS)       (cost  3.3))
(path (start G)(end H) (path G,g,f,e,H)      (cost  5.2))
(path (start G)(end I) (path G,g,k,n,m,I)    (cost  6.5))

(path (start H)(end A) (path H,e,d,n,m,a,A)  (cost 10.3))
(path (start H)(end B) (path H,e,f,g,B)      (cost  6.5))
(path (start H)(end C) (path H,e,d,C)        (cost  3.8))
(path (start H)(end D) (path H,e,d,c,D)      (cost  5.8))
(path (start H)(end E) (path H,e,d,n,E)      (cost  6.8))
(path (start H)(end F) (path H,e,f,F)        (cost  3.8))
(path (start H)(end CS)(path H,e,f,g,k,CS)   (cost  6.5))
(path (start H)(end H) (path H,e,f,g,H)      (cost  5.2))
(path (start H)(end I) (path H,e,d,n,m,I)    (cost  8.8))

(path (start I)(end A) (path I,m,a,A)        (cost  3.5))
(path (start I)(end B) (path I,m,n,k,g,b,B)  (cost 7.8))
(path (start I)(end C) (path I,m,n,d,c,C)    (cost  9))
(path (start I)(end D) (path I,m,n,d,D)      (cost  7))
(path (start I)(end E) (path I,m,n,E)        (cost  4))
(path (start I)(end F) (path I,m,n,k,g,f,F)  (cost  7.9))
(path (start I)(end CS)(path I,m,m,k,CS)     (cost  5.2))
(path (start I)(end G) (path I,m,n,k,g,G)    (cost  6.5))
(path (start I)(end H) (path I,m,n,d,e,I)    (cost 8.8)))

 (defrule lancesaisiepoint
?f1 <-  (debut node)
=>
    (retract ?f1)
    (printout t "how many node start")
    (bind ?x (read))
    (assert (startnode ?x))
 )

(defrule saisiepoint
?f <-   (startnode ?a)
    (test (> ?a 0))
=>
 (printout t " Enter nbr node start" crlf)
(printout t "start node name ")
(bind ?start (read))
(printout t "node start value ")
(bind ?y1 (read))
(assert (startnode ?start ?y1))
(retract ?f)
(assert (startnode (- ?a 1)))
)

(defrule lancesaisiemoins
?f1 <-  (startnode 0)
=>
(retract ?f1)
(printout t "how many node end ")
(bind ?x (read))
(assert (endnode ?x))
 )

(defrule saisiemoins
?f <-   (endnode ?a)
(test (> ?a 0))
=>
(printout t "Enter nbr node end" crlf)
(printout t "end node name ")
(bind ?end (read))
(printout t "node end value ")
(bind ?y2 (read))
(assert (endnode ?end ?y2))
(retract ?f)
(assert (endnode (- ?a 1))))


(defrule supprnbrpoint ;compter
?x<-    (startnode 0)
=>
    (retract ?x)
    )

(defrule supprnbrmoins
?x<-    (endnode 0)
=>
    (retract ?x)
    )

(defrule info

 ?M <- (startnode ?start ?y1)
 ?K <- (endnode ?end ?y2)
  =>
(assert (start ?start end ?end)))


(defrule var  

 ?e1 <-(startnode ?start ?)
 ?f1 <-(endnode ?end ?)
 (path (start ?start) (end ?end) (path $?path) (cost ?cost))

(not (and (startnode ?start$? ?)
       (path (start ?start$?) (end ?end) (cost ?cost?&:(< ?cost? ?cost)))))
   =>


   (printout t " PATH  " ?start " to " ?end " by " ?path " with a cost of  " ?cost  crlf)
   (assert (info (start ?start) (end ?end) (path $?path) (cost ?cost))))

(defrule var1 

    ?e2 <-(startnode ?start ?)
    ?f2 <-(endnode ?end ?)
   (path (start ?start) (end ?end) (path $?path) (cost ?cost))

(not (and (endnode ?end$? ?)
 (path (start ?start) (end ?end$?) (cost ?cost2&:
(< ?cost2 ?cost)))))
  =>

  (printout t " PATH  " ?start " to " ?end " by " ?path " with  a cost of  " ?cost  crlf)
  (assert (info (start ?start) (end ?end) (path $?path) (cost 
?cost))))
```

[this pict show  the result if i have the number of start node equal to the number of end node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ix6O.png)

[this pict show the result when we have the number of start node greedy than the end node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcBYh.png)

so when  i applied the rule given by @GRAY i have the same 3 result combinaison for any number superior of 3 . 
what i expect is to have all combinaison of the number of input ( between nmr start node and end node) of corse withe the lowest cost .
i tried with the retract but it give a different result may be i place it rong in the code.

and what if i use a different solution ,for example a class or a function ??? but i am still new in this field so i don t know what i can do , thank you very much for your help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple rules detecting the shortest paths, you need to add a pattern to each of the rules to exclude the paths detected by the other rules.

In this case, you can add the pattern "(not (info (start ?start) (end ?end)))" to the var and var1 rules to exclude the previously detected patterns:

```
(defrule var
   ?e1 <- (startnode ?start ?)
   ?f1 <- (endnode ?end ?)
   (path (start ?start) (end ?end) (path $?path) (cost ?cost))
   (not (and (startnode ?start$? ?)
             (path (start ?start$?) (end ?end) (cost ?cost?&:(< ?cost? ?cost)))))
   (not (info (start ?start) (end ?end)))
   =>
   (printout t " PATH  " ?start " to " ?end " by " ?path " with a cost of  " ?cost crlf)
   (assert (info (start ?start) (end ?end) (path $?path) (cost ?cost))))

(defrule var1
   ?e2 <- (startnode ?start ?)
   ?f2 <- (endnode ?end ?)
   (path (start ?start) (end ?end) (path $?path) (cost ?cost))
   (not (and (endnode ?end$? ?)
             (path (start ?start) (end ?end$?) (cost ?cost2&:(< ?cost2 ?cost)))))
   (not (info (start ?start) (end ?end)))
   =>
   (printout t " PATH  " ?start " to " ?end " by " ?path " with  a cost of  " ?cost crlf)
   (assert (info (start ?start) (end ?end) (path $?path) (cost ?cost))))
```

Comment: Ok ,i did it and it s work ,thank you for your help , i learn more and more from you every day ,thank you Mr @Gary